# correct way to setup teardown login logout in django

Tags: python, django, testing

To test a polling app that I made using django, the pre-requisite for voting/viewing_results is that the user should be logged in. I wanted to create a testsuite where setup involves creating testuser, logging him in and teardown involves logging out the user and deleting the user.

I came across the setUp() and tearDown() methods - but got to know that they are done for each method in the test. I wanted to have this functionality at the class level and saw that django has setUpClass and tearDownClass - but as they are class methods I cannot do self.client.login , self.client.logout on them. I then created a LoginMixin which has setUp and tearDown methods.

I wanted to know which of these 2 methods is more pythonic and is there a better alternative rather than logging in and out before every test?

1. Have setUp, tearDown methods:

   ```
   def setUp(self):
       self.user = utils.create_user()
       self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testpasswd')

   def tearDown(self):
       self.client.logout()
       utils.delete_user(self.user)
   ```
2. Have a LoginMixin and let each test class derive from it:

   ```
   class LoginMixin():

     def setUp(self):
       self.user = create_user()
       self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testpasswd')

     def tearDown(self):
       self.client.logout()

   class MyTest(LoginMixin, TestCase):
      ....
      ....
   ```

I am using django_nose as the TestRunner.

Comment: what app/module are you using to test? WebTest?

Comment: Using django_nose as the Testrunner - the tests have been written using the usual django unit testing as described here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: well, do like in the TestCase docs. Create a class whose name is `Something(TestCase)`. Then, for this class, create `setUp` and `tearDown` (they get called each time a function inside `Something` class gets called. Then create the function tests you need(name must begin with `test_....`. And of course, the setUp and tearDown will do the login/logout

Comment: Have done that as per the original post but setup, teardown get called for each method and the functionality i want to achieve is to login/logout at the class level - login - run all the tests in this class - logout. And the methods need to use the client object - but they can't because class methods will login at the class level and not at the object level. So I wanted to know what's the best practice people normally follow.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you're not using the `setUpClass` classmethod is because you don't have access to the default Client, you could just create your own and refer to that:

```
from django.test.client import Client

class LoginMixin():
    client = Client()
    # ...
```